# Can anyone explain Explain in one sentence what the following Python/JES function is doing?

Tags: jython

```
 def mysterious(pic):
     w =getWidth(pic)
     h = getHeight(pic)
     for y in range(1, h+1):
       for x in range(1, w/2+1):
         p1 = getPixel(pic, x, y)
         p2 = getPixel(pic, w-x+1, h-y+1)
         c1 = getColor(p1)
         setColor(p1, getColor(p2))
         setColor(p2, c1)
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: You're about to get a run-on sentence.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like the picture's color is getting inverted from one end to another.

The pixel color at the end of the picture is being inserted at the beginning of the picture and vice versa.

The code also depends on the height and width of the picture. It controls the for loop, so depending on that, the amount of pixels will change color